# Can't bind selected checkbox values with livewire component

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get all checkbox values as an array.

Blade:

```
<button wire:click.prevent="export">
   Export selected
</button>
<div>
@foreach($hotels as $hotel)
   <input type="checkbox" wire:model="selectedRows" value="{{ $hotel->id }}">
   <label>{{ $hotel->name }}</label>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Component:

```
public $selectedRows = [];

public function export() {
   dd($this->selectedRows);
}
```

The result I get is an empty array. Any suggestions?

Comment: As per shared code, if you are getting empty array then it is working fine. Because you never assigned anything value to object `selectedRows`.

Comment: So, how can I assign a value? @BlueSuiter

Comment: You have to retrieve the data set and then assign it `selectedRows`

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: @BlueSuiter Perhaps you could provide a working example in an answer?

Comment: Replace `public $selectedRows = [];` with `public $selectedRows = ['a', 'b', 'c'];` and let me know the result.

Comment: @BlueSuiter I get an array result:
`
array:3 [
  0 => "a"
  1 => "b"
  2 => "c"
]
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to put a button also inside the div tag:

```
<div>
   <button wire:click.prevent="export">
      Export selected
   </button>
   @foreach($hotels as $hotel)
      <input type="checkbox" wire:model="selectedRows" value="{{ $hotel->id }}">
      <label>{{ $hotel->name }}</label>
   @endforeach
</div>
```